# What is the C# version of this simple F# code to construct a basic Windows.Form?

Tags: c#, f#

I'm just starting to learn F# and C# together. The following F# code is a
slightly tweaked example from Chris Smith's Programming F# book.

What would the equivalent in C# look like?

```fs
open System.Windows.Forms

let form = new Form(Text="Click Me", TopMost=true)

form.MouseClick.AddHandler(
  new MouseEventHandler(
    fun sender clickArgs -> printfn "MouseClickEvent @ [%d, %d] %O" clickArgs.X clickArgs.Y clickArgs.Button
  )
);;

form.ShowDialog();;
```

Comment: FWIW, here's a slightly more idiomatic way of attaching to that click event from F#: `form.MouseClick |> Event.add (fun clickArgs -> printfn "MouseClickEvent @ [%d, %d] %O" clickArgs.X clickArgs.Y clickArgs.Button)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fumbling in the dark since I don't know F#, but here goes:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Answer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Form form = new Form { Text = "Click Me", TopMost = true };

            form.MouseClick += (s, e) => {
                System.Console.WriteLine("MouseClickEvent @ [{0}, {1}] {2}", 
                    e.X.ToString("d"), 
                    e.Y.ToString("d"), 
                    e.Button.ToString()
                );
            };

            form.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what the `form.Click += etc.` construct is or give me the term for it so I can look it up?

Comment: @dan: The `(s, e) => { ... }` bit is called a lambda expression. It's one of the (simpler) ways to specify an event handler delegate which you want to subscribe to events (`+=`) with in C# - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx

Comment: +1 Beat me to it!  I was only going to add ToString("d") for e.X and e.Y.  I was in the process of finding out what the "%O" specifier is.

Comment: @Jay Riggs: I added the `ToString("d")`s to my answer. I checked and `%O` seems to just mean regular old `ToString()`.

Comment: Thank you! I just compiled it (using mono gmcs) and it works exactly like the F# version. I appreciate the explanation too.